# Unable to write into Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried diff versions of firebase dependencies and enabled all Google APIs but to no avail.

The rules for my firebase for read and write are both set to true.
I want to write Hello in my database, Under the reference Location 1.

My pubyaml dependencies are as follows:

```
dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.0
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_database: ^7.0.0
```

My app build Gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

My code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:trackkit/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:trackkit/LoginSignup/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';


class AddItem extends StatelessWidget{
  AddItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    DatabaseReference location = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Location 1");
    
    return Scaffold(
        body:Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Product name',
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Save'),
          onPressed: () async  {
              await location
                  .push()
                  .set({"hello"});
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

After I pressed the 'Save' Button
The console log shows :

```
E/flutter ( 4825): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: LinkedHashSet len:1
E/flutter ( 4825): #0      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:426:7)
E/flutter ( 4825): #1      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:423:9)
E/flutter ( 4825): #2      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:400:8)
E/flutter ( 4825): #3      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:421:13)
E/flutter ( 4825): #4      StandardMethodCodec.encodeMethodCall (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:561:18)
E/flutter ( 4825): #5      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:148:13)
E/flutter ( 4825): #6      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
E/flutter ( 4825): #7      MethodChannelDatabaseReference.set (package:firebase_database_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_database_reference.dart:97:42)
E/flutter ( 4825): #8      DatabaseReference.set (package:firebase_database/src/database_reference.dart:72:39)
E/flutter ( 4825): #9      AddItem.build.<anonymous closure> (package:trackkit/Screens/addnewitem.dart:30:20)
E/flutter ( 4825): #10     AddItem.build.<anonymous closure> (package:trackkit/Screens/addnewitem.dart:28:22)
E/flutter ( 4825): #11     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
E/flutter ( 4825): #12     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:193:24)
E/flutter ( 4825): #13     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
E/flutter ( 4825): #14     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
E/flutter ( 4825): #15     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
E/flutter ( 4825): #16     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:558:9)
E/flutter ( 4825): #17     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
E/flutter ( 4825): #18     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
E/flutter ( 4825): #19     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:400:8)
E/flutter ( 4825): #20     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
E/flutter ( 4825): #21     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
E/flutter ( 4825): #22     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:19)
E/flutter ( 4825): #23     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:22)
E/flutter ( 4825): #24     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:278:11)
E/flutter ( 4825): #25     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
E/flutter ( 4825): #26     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
E/flutter ( 4825): #27     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
E/flutter ( 4825): #28     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
E/flutter ( 4825): #29     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1444:13)
E/flutter ( 4825): #30     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 4825): #31     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter ( 4825): #32     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:185:10)
E/flutter ( 4825): #33     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
E/flutter ( 4825): #34     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:98:31)
```

I have been trying for 2 days, any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Shouldn't you need to set a key to pair with the data that you're setting? i.e. `({"msg" : "hello"})` https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage#modifying-data

Comment: That indeed seems to be it @Omatt: you can either specify a key/value pair (as in your `({"msg" : "hello"})`) or just value (`("hello")` without the curly braces). Can you write that up in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to set a key-value pair if you're trying to write with curly braces `({"msg" : "hello"})`. If not, then you just need to remove the curly brace and write it as `("hello")` as mentioned by puf. More details can be read in the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage/#modifying-data).

Answer (score 0):

In a more general way, I'd say you need to make sure the data you're sending to Firebase is in the right format.

For example, make sure you're sending JSON, and not entities.